# A SQL exception was caught. The error was: ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have created a trigger with the below code

```
create or replace trigger DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL
after update
on attrvaldesc
FOR Each row
when (new.field2 is null)
Declare
attrvaloriginal attrval.attrval_id%TYPE;
attrval_id attrval.attrval_id%TYPE;
language_id attrvaldesc.language_id%type;
storeent_id attrval.storeent_id%type;
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
Begin
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(:OLD.attrval_id);
select attrval_id into attrvaloriginal from attrval where identifier = (select identifier||'_original' from attrval where attrval_id= :OLD.attrval_id and storeent_id=10051) and storeent_id=10051;
if (attrvaloriginal > 0) then
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(attrvaloriginal);
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(:NEW.value);
delete from attrval where attrval_id = attrvaloriginal and storeent_id=10051;
commit;
END IF;
End;
```

The trigger has compiled and when i trigger a job which updates attrvaldesc table, I'm facing the below exception

Exception message:

> A SQL exception was caught. The error was: ORA-04098: trigger 'WCS_ADMIN_HFI.DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL' is invalid and failed re-validation
>
> Stack trace:
>   com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.exception.DataLoadSQLException: A SQL exception was caught. The error was: ORA-04098: trigger 'WCS_ADMIN_HFI.DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL' is invalid and failed re-validation

To check if any errors in my trigger I did a

```
SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL;
```

I returned the below

> 18/1 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP"

Comment: Your trigger doesn't have 'drop' - are you sure you have the right version loaded? Ah, it also doesn't have 18 lines either, so did you create it as part of a bigger script, and just left out the `/` to execute the `create trigger`? You need that since it's PL/SQL.

Comment: yeah i didnt add / at the end. Let me try that

Comment: Its working now. Thanks Alex!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown doesn't include the word 'drop'. But the error message also refers to line 18. In a trigger a PLS error only refers to the PL/SQL section, starting with `declare` or `begin`. Your PL/SQL section only has 16 lines, from `declare` to `end;`. This indicates the problem is not quite in what you've shown.

From that we can deduce that you've created your trigger as part of a script, and the next statement was dropping an object:

```
create or replace trigger DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL
...
End;

drop ...
```

Because it's PL/SQL the trigger creation [needs to be submitted with a `/` character](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663). At the moment everything after your actual trigger, down to the next time a `/` appears in your script (or the end of the script, potentially), is being accidentally included as part of the trigger definition, which means it's including things that are not valid PL/SQL. From the error that includes a `drop`, but it may also include other statements, dropping, creating or altering any number of objects.

So you need to add a slash after the trigger in your script:

```
create or replace trigger DTE_SAVE_ORIGINAL_VAL
...
End;
/

drop ...
```

You can just re-run the trigger statement on its own, but bear in mind that whatever followed it - everything that was accidentally treated as part of the trigger - was not executed at all, so you may be missing other objects, or have them built differently to how you expect (if the script was supposed to drop and then recreate objects).

You *might* want to fix and then re-run the whole script, as long as you haven't added any data that would destroy - which is likely if you're now updating data. If that isn't a safe thing to do then see what else wasn't done, and execute those parts manually too, again watching out for potential data loss.